# A more suitable Timeline

Tags: datetime

I am looking for some LaTex timeline, which should look like something as below:

[image]

Edit 1: I did check the `pgfgantt package` but it doesn't provide as cool a timeline as above.
Edit 2: The minimal code is from  [pgfcantt.pdf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en). The diagram on its page 48, would work for me too. But I can't reproduce it with the following minimal code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt Charts with the pgfgantt Package}
\begin{document}

%
% A fairly complicated example from section 2.9 of the package
% documentation. This reproduces an example from Wikipedia:
% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart
%
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{13}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{WEEKS:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,13}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup[progress=57]{WBS 1 Summary Element 1}{1}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=75,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.1} Activity A}{1}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=67,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.2} Activity B}{1}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=50,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.3} Activity C}{4}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.4} Activity D}{4}{10} \\[grid]
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 2 Summary Element 2}{4}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.1} Activity E}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.2} Activity F}{6}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.3} Activity G}{9}{10}
  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{WBS1A}{WBS1B}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{WBS1B}{WBS1C}
  \ganttlink[
    link type=f-f,
    link label node/.append style=left
  ]{WBS1C}{WBS1D}
\end{ganttchart}

%
% A simpler example from the package documentation:
%
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
  \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
  \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
  \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These are called [Gantt charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).

Comment: Can't reproduce it in what way? What happens? Do you get an error? Is the output unexpected? Just copy-pasting code from somewhere else and saying it doesn't work is not very informative. I mean, how should we know why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have searched the pgfgannt.pdf file (documentation for pgfgannt.sty) as referenced by the O.P. and I cannot find this diagram or the code posted above.  Is this possibly from a different manual or document?

Comment: @R.Schumacher sorry it is on page 48 of the same link https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en

Comment: @R.Schumacher I made it worked. Updated code is now working. Thanks.

Comment: Does "Updated code is now working" mean that there been an answer to this question?  If so, I would think that posting it as an answer would be good.

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, it works. Actually what I was initially interested to draw it is not exactly doing that but it do serve my purpose to satisfactory extent.

Comment: Why don't you post your code as the Answer then.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt Charts with the pgfgantt Package}
\begin{document}

%
% A fairly complicated example from section 2.9 of the package
% documentation. This reproduces an example from Wikipedia:
% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart
%
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=7,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{13}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{WEEKS:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,13}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup[progress=57]{WBS 1 Summary Element 1}{1}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=75,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.1} Activity A}{1}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=67,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.2} Activity B}{1}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=50,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.3} Activity C}{4}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\textbf{WBS 1.4} Activity D}{4}{10} \\[grid]
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 2 Summary Element 2}{4}{10} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.1} Activity E}{4}{5} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.2} Activity F}{6}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{WBS 2.3} Activity G}{9}{10}
  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{WBS1A}{WBS1B}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{WBS1B}{WBS1C}
  \ganttlink[
    link type=f-f,
    link label node/.append style=left
  ]{WBS1C}{WBS1D}
\end{ganttchart}

%
% A simpler example from the package documentation:
%
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
  \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
  \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
  \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]